# find the errors and fix them. this program is to find the sum of multiples of 3 in array

Tags: python-3.x, list, error-handling

this program is to find the sum of multiples of 3 in array. help me located the erros to make it work.

```
values = [1,3,"5",7,8,9]
multiples_of_three = []
total_of_threes = 0

while not (i > values.lenght):
    if (values[i] modulo 3) ==0:
        multiples_of_three[i] == values[i]
        
while True:
    if not multiples_of_three.empty():
        total_of_threes = total_of_threes + multiples_of_three.first_item
        multiples_of_three.remove_first_item
    else if multiples_of_three.empty():
        break
print (total_of_threes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want.

For now, I made a prediction and wrote the answer.

If not the result you want, write the details in the comments.

Try this code (python style):

```
values = [1, 3, "5", 7, 8, 9]

result = 0
for value in values:
    if int(value) % 3 == 0:
        result += value

print(result)
```

If you want a use the list, solution 1 :

```
values = [1, 3, "5", 7, 8, 9]
multiples_of_three = []

result = 0
for value in values:
    if int(value) % 3 == 0:
        multiples_of_three.append(value)

for value in multiples_of_three:
    result += value

print(result)
```

If you want a use the list, solution 2 :

```
values = [1, 3, "5", 7, 8, 9]
multiples_of_three = []

result = 0
for value in values:
    if int(value) % 3 == 0:
        multiples_of_three.append(value)

print(sum(multiples_of_three))
```